# convergence of sum of squares over squared sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, sums-of-squares

If we have $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^2_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i)^2}$ where $a_i$ is a positive sequence where each element is finite with probability 1, under which set of conditions does the division converge to $0$ as n approaches infinity?. I am sure the next statement is true:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^2_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i)^2}\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^2_i}{\sum_{i\neq j} a_ia_j}
\end{equation}
Is there maybe a way to show the denominator in the RHS grows faster than the numerator under some additional assumptions?

Comment: I'll suggest you compute the limit for sequences that divergences quickly (eg. exponentially $a_k \propto \lambda^k$ ) diverges not that quick (eg. polynomially $a_k \propto k^\alpha)$ and divergences really slow (eg. $a_k \propto \log k$) and see whether you can observe any pattern.

Comment: Indeed I will. Thank you for the suggestion. I made a change to the problem setup where now each element in the sequence is finite with probability 1.  I am thinking along the lines of an exponential random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\space i \space$ is an integer.

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^2_i}{\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\big)^2}
&=
\dfrac{
\dfrac{n(n_+1)(2n+1)}{6}
}{
\bigg(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg)^2}\\ \\
&=\dfrac{4n(n_+1)(2n+1)
}{
6n^2(n+1)^2}\\\\
&=\dfrac{2(2n+1)}{3n(n+1)}
\end{align*}

Since the numerator is linear and the denominator is quadratic, it appears that the series tends to zero.

Comment: Interesting. Why is the first equality true? is there a reference I can use? Also you mean $a_i$ is an integer?. Thank you

Comment: @UniformIntegrability The numerator and denominator of the RHS are formulas for the sum of powers, readily available at places like  halfway down the page [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a condition where it **isn't** true. If $a_i \ge c a_{i-1}$ for all $i$, where $c > 1$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \frac{c}{c-1} a_n$$
so $$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2} \ge \left(\frac{c-1}{c}\right)^2$$
does not converge to $0$.

Comment: brilliant!. I think an interesting alternative to the setup is that each element in the sequence $a_n$ is still positive but  finite with probability 1 for all n. Then a different condition would be needed to negate the convergence.